# Bitbucket pipelines issues with git commands

Tags: git, bash, heroku, continuous-integration, bitbucket

I am new to bitbucket pipelines service and I have problems with deploying my app to heroku.

My bitbucket-pipelines.yml file is here:

```
image: php:5.6.31
clone: 
 depth: fullpipelines: 
default: 
 - step: 
  script: 
   - php -v  
   - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD
```

Building app fails with "bash: git: command not found". Does this mean that I have to simply write git-installing script before pushing it to heroku?

Answer (score 2):

Just had to add

```
 - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip git
```

before pushing command