# Heroku PHP with bitbucket-pipelines.yml - git command not found

Tags: git, heroku, laravel-5, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I spent hours and only found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632283/bitbucket-pipelines-issues-with-git-commands), but the solution didn't help me.

## My setup

- Laravel PHP info app with phpinfo view, no extras
- Bitbucket Cloud with Heroku pipeline
- Heroku app accordingly configured

**The problem is**, when I push changes to Bitbucket and these are **then pushed to Heroku**, the **git command is not found**.

Please see my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` in link to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/DBGBHavE).

When the pipeline step "Deploy to Heroku" runs, it aborts saying

```
+ git push 
https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD

bash: git: command not found
```

In the build setup, the installation of git successfully finishes. See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCVWq.png).

Why does the git command afterwards fail?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Reason for failure was, that in the second step the git components were not installed.

Please find corrected version below.

```
# This is a sample build configuration for PHP.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/e8YWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: php:7.1.3

pipelines:
default:
- step:
  name: Set up the docker container
  caches:
- composer
  script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip git git-core libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev 
&&   rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  - docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl && docker-php-ext- 
install   -j$(nproc) imap
  - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin 
-- filename=composer
- composer install
- vendor/bin/phpunit

- step:
# set HEROKU_API_KEY and HEROKU_APP_NAME environment variables
# set clone `depth: full' as described here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/Y9- 
  5Mw
  name: Deploy to Heroku
  deployment: test # set to test, staging or production
# trigger: manual # uncomment to have a manual step
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip git git-core libc-client-dev libkrb5- 
    dev && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
  - git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_KEY@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git HEAD
```